# How to share Drupal code across multisites that are each in subdirectories?

Tags: installation, multi-sites

I have two websites on my own server (I have full control of the Apache config, etc.)

I want to install Drupal 'into' each of them, in a subdirectory of the site root.

I'd like to share a Drupal codebase between the two.

And, I'd like to have the URLs appear without the subdirectory.

My problem is I can't figure out how to do all at once.

I can get to this easily,

```
/src/www
  /website1
    /drupal1
       ...
       sites/website1.com/themes/website1.com
       ...
    /other_stuff_1a
    /other_stuff_1b
  /website2
    /drupal2
       ...
       sites/website2.com/themes/website2.com
       ...
    /other_stuff_2a
    /other_stuff_2b
```

But I'm not sure how to share the Drupal7 code in this case.  Do I have to use symlinks or something?

I'd appreciate any help or ideas.

Frank

Answer (score 1):

Drupal come with already a multi site feature, you ca read more about it [here](http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site).

After, if for some reasons you don't want install Drupal with multi-site and keep the both separate in your server, you can still use Git or SVN and co.

The idea is simple, you've the same codebase for development and multiple `clone` or `checkout` in your server. For example, in your case it will be `drupal1` and `drupal2`.